# How to let apple script respond to a choose dialog with specified file path

Tags: applescript

in this case, the application is opening up a dialog and ask user to choose a file,
in the automation script the file location is known in environment variable, so how to use apple script to finish choosing from the dialog? and dismiss the dialog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144521/how-to-select-file-using-applescript-in-finder-prompt) to be the correct solution.

in short: when a dialogue is open, we can type "/" to input path string, where we can do paste actions, and then we can confirm by type "*return*"